# Alternative for Dreamweaver that has a "template" feature and JQuery & PHP visual assistance

Tags: php, jquery, css, ide, dreamweaver

I'm looking for an alternative for Dreamweaver. I'm not using it much lately. DW used to be a good designing tool, but recently, with the mass introduction of JS and PHP, it's not as useful any longer. I hardly use the visual designer at all. Not to tell that nowadays things like html img tags for templates are very outdated. Everything is done using CSS and DW doesn't have a visual designer that allows me to easily create DIVs styled with CSS.

Basically, the most important feature for me is the "templates" one, because I design static websites and DW has this feature in which I can make a "template" and make editable regions, so I don't have to use only CSS for theming, I just create a template, and whenever I want to change the appearance of an entire website, I just have to edit its template, and DW will automatically update all pages to that style, but keeping the specific parts (editable regions). It's like a CMS but produces static pages, I use PHP only where its really needed.

PHP and JQuery coding assistance and debugging are also important.

Any recommendations?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377741/need-a-wysiwyg-php-javascript-ide-replacement-for-dreamweaver

Comment: its not a duplicate because i don't want a wysiwyg editor.

Comment: Did you find anything yet? Searching for the same thing...

Comment: @ɹoƃı Nope, Unfortunately. I ended up using php. :(. It's a pity this question was closed imho. It seems there's no alternative for Dreamweaver if you're counting on the 'templates' feature. If the server has PHP then it's okay to use it, so i'm gonna mark Derek's answer as accepted. It's not quite what I was expecting but it's kinda okay imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans http://netbeans.org

Eclipse http://www.eclipse.org/

If you are using PHP you should have a header and footer 'template' which is included in each of your site's pages. This allows you to edit a single file and it show up on all of your pages.

I use Notepad++ http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: I've checked both and couldn't find any feature like the templates in DW. I could use PHP but this is extra processing, so little though...

Comment: Yes, using PHP is okay, but sometimes you just don't want/have it. Thanks nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Mac, look at [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/).  I've found it to be the best IDE for web development for Macs and it is relatively cheap.  I'm not sure if it has exactly the type of templating feature you are looking for, but it does have a WYSIWYG edit mode and if you use CSS, you can just apply one style sheet to each page an only have to update that style sheet.